# Duplicate cell data based on cell value and 1 condition

Tags: excel, vba

i have the below sheet named as  (weekly plane) i need to copy D column value x times as same as value on column B if only column M value is **new** and paste it anther sheet named as (Trip tracking) on column c and each time i do this to be pasted at end of current data.

[image]

i did this code to copy and paste values but i unable to set the if condition belong

```
Sub copy()

'----variables
Dim lrow_d As Long
Dim lrow_s As Long

'-----Sheets
Dim week As Worksheet
Dim trip As Worksheet

'-----Define Sheet names
Set week = Worksheets("Weekly plan")
Set trip = Worksheets("Trip tracking")

'--LastRow
lrow_s = week.Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrow_s

lrow_d = trip.Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

week.Range("D" & i).copy Destination:=trip.Range("C" & lrow_d + 1 & ":" & "C" & lrow_d + week.Range("B" & i))

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the expected results in `Trip tracking`?

Comment: Maybe `if week.Range("M" & i).value = "New" then trip.range Range("C" & lrow_d + 1).resize(week.range("B" & i),1).value = week.range("D" & i).value` ? Not tested.